# How do I name a drupal page template file according to a node's url path setting?

Tags: file, templates, drupal, filenames

I'm new to drupal and having trouble naming a page template file. In drupal 7, let's say I've created a basic page with the url path as:

```
www.example.com/my-page
```

When I create a custom page template file, I've been able to get the file name page--node--[nid].tpl.php to work fine.  However, I have 3 different sites (localhost, development, and production) and each has a different node id for this page (because the databases aren't sync'd).  I need to find a way to name the template file according to the url path.  I've tried all of the following, none of which has worked:

```
page--my-page.tpl.php
page--my_page.tpl.php
page--node--my-page.tpl.php
page--node--my_page.tpl.php
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194109/drupal-7-candidate-page-tpl-name-for-particular-custom-content-type-entry

Comment: Read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268003/using-front-tpl-in-drupal-7-for-another-page/8268541#8268541

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.  With it you should be able to get a list of possible template names that are being considered.